# Grid View Generic Functions

Tags: asp.net, gridview

currently I am using few generic functions/methods in gridview for Sorting Images and Getting Header Row in TH and merge Header Row.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120721045113/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ram/archive/2006/07/13/GridViewGenericSortImagesFunction.aspx)
http://marss.co.ua/MergingGridViewHeaderColumns.aspx

problem is i have to write these function for every Grid. I looking for solution, Where I can define these behaviors only at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object that inherits from the GridView.  Add your properties and functionality to that new object.  On your page add that new object instead of the GridView.   And if you go totally nuts like I did, you can end up creating a totally different control.  See the
[GridViewTree.](http://www.DigitalTools.com/GVT.aspx)